# JQuery remove key and its value from an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to remove a key called age from an array.

I tried below splice, but didnt help me removing the key and retain other keys and values in an array.

```
$(data).splice("age",1);
```

Here is my full code that outputs an array

```
var data = {'fname': 'John', 'lname': 'Smith', 'age': 29, 'job': 'Agent' };

$(data).splice("age",1);

console.log(data);
```

Here is [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/qpkhcqaf/) that demonstrates above example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `delete data.age;` to remove your item from the object in JavaScript.

It seems like you were thinking of the object more like an array, whereas objects get special treatment in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you. :) That works for sure. But I am trying to figure it out how I can accomplish this with pure JQuery.

Comment: @Ray Pardon for asking, but why do you want to use jQuery for this when the JavaScript is already a one-liner?

Comment: I have heard from others that some users dont have javascript enabled and delete might not work. Correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: @Ray jQuery is a JavaScript framework, so if your users have JavaScript disabled, jQuery will not run.

Comment: gotcha... in that case there is no point for me spending more time on when JavaScript can do a fine job with one line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `delete` like

```js
var data = {'fname': 'John', 'lname': 'Smith', 'age': 29, 'job': 'Agent' };
delete data.age;
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks AmmarCSE, That does the trick. However, I am trying to figure out this with pure JQuery and not using delete from javascript which may not be available in all browsers.